# ACF Blocks enqueue style in head

Tags: wordpress-gutenberg, acf-gutenberg

I tried to add acf block tyle via acf_register_block_type, but it is loading in footer. How to place styles in the header?

Answer (score -1):

You should add your registration code as an example, but styles (enqueued in the theme or bock) wp_enqueue_style(). Styles enqueued in this way are automatically added to the `<head>`. It's not common practice for `<link rel="stylesheet">` to be added to the end of `</body>`.